# Sass/css wont render in cloud9 polling-fallback error

Tags: sass, cloud9-ide, aws-cloud9

My sass or css files are rendering and i got this pooling fallback error.

Does anyone know what this error means?

```
 carlagoncalves:~/workspace (master) $ node server.js
    server running....
    ^C
    carlagoncalves:~/workspace (master) $ node app.js
    carlagoncalves:~/workspace (master) $ sass --watch styles.scss:styles.css
    >>> Sass is watching for changes. Press Ctrl-C to stop.
          error No such file or directory @ rb_sysopen - styles.scss
    Ignoring executable-hooks-1.3.2 because its extensions are not built.  Try: gem pristine executable-hooks --version 1.3.2
    Ignoring ffi-1.9.23 because its extensions are not built.  Try: gem pristine ffi --version 1.9.23
    Ignoring gem-wrappers-1.2.7 because its extensions are not built.  Try: gem pristine gem-wrappers --version 1.2.7
    [Listen warning]:
      Listen will be polling for changes. Learn more at https://github.com/guard/listen#polling-fallback.
    ^Ccarlagoncalves:~/workspace (master) $ sass --watch styles.sass:styles.css 
    >>> Sass is watching for changes. Press Ctrl-C to stop.
    Ignoring executable-hooks-1.3.2 because its extensions are not built.  Try: gem pristine executable-hooks --version 1.3.2
    Ignoring ffi-1.9.23 because its extensions are not built.  Try: gem pristine ffi --version 1.9.23
    Ignoring gem-wrappers-1.2.7 because its extensions are not built.  Try: gem pristine gem-wrappers --version 1.2.7
    [Listen warning]:
      Listen will be polling for changes. Learn more at https://github.com/guard/listen#polling-fallback.
```

[image]

Answer (score 0):

As it says in the error message, the file *styles.s**c**ss* cannot be found:

```
error No such file or directory @ rb_sysopen - styles.scss
```

It seems there is a file called *styles.sass* in your directory, so you could try changing your command to the following:

```
$ sass --watch styles.sass:styles.css
```

---

Also, it seems there are unbuilt extensions, which you can try to fix by using the commands specified in the error messages (a couple of examples below)

```
Try: gem pristine executable-hooks --version 1.3.2
Try: gem pristine ffi --version 1.9.23
Try: gem pristine gem-wrappers --version 1.2.7
```

Comment: I'be tried that solution before and now that you mentioned i just tried again and this is what i got :
[Listen warning]:
  Listen will be polling for changes. Learn more at https://github.com/guard/listen#polling-fallback.

Comment: The gems are installed and updated so i really dont know why is doing that